# PowerPoint- How to make an animation appear when multiple triggers have been selected?

Tags: powerpoint

Today I've been making a quiz inside PowerPoint. In this quiz, the user has to select five of the seven countries that the Amazon River runs through.

I have a slide full of text boxes. Seven text boxes (out of perhaps 30) do contain countries that the Amazon River runs through. The rest contain countries that the Amazon River does *not* run through.

When in presentation mode, the user has ten guesses. In these ten, they have to select five countries that the Amazon River runs through.

I need to do two things:

**If the user selects five correct countries, and has not gone over his/her limit of ten guesses, a PowerPoint animation runs.** This animation will be connected to another text box that says "You Win!"

**If the user has selected more than ten different countries, and has not gotten five countries correct, a different PowerPoint animation runs.** This animation will be connected to another text box that says "You Lose. Better luck next time."

Are these goals achievable? Remember, there are *seven* correct text boxes. The user only has to get *five* correct.

I'm fine with using macros, as long as the answer lays out clearly what to do.

Comment: People won't write a solution for you if you cannot show what you have tried so far. Also, it's not morning for everybody on the world :P

Comment: @NoelWidmer Please, you don't need to find fault in a simple "good morning".

Comment: Saying good morning is not a fault. It simply isn't true for all readers, especially when your post gets read in the future. And it doesn't add any value to your question. I just wanted to bring it to your attention so you can leave it out next time. The first part of my comment is much more important.